# How many zeroes are there at the end of the sum $1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + \cdots+ 100^{100}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

> Find the number of zeroes at the end of the sum 
>   $$1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + \cdots+ 100^{100}$$

I tried a lot and my answer came 4700 but it was not correct.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%5En+from+n%3D1+to+n%3D100).

Comment: Do you mind sharing your solution? (as I don't have a good idea on how to approach this problem).

Comment: Note that this number is less than $100^{101}$ which has only 203 digits.  It would be very strange indeed if 4700 of those were zeroes.

Comment: @LordSoth ya i dont have any problem..u can share..

Comment: @SoumajitDas I don't understand... You said you tried something and came up with $4700$. I wanted to know what have you tried.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=1^1 +2^2 +3^3 +\cdots+100^{100}.$

$\phi(5^2)=20,(a,5)=1\implies a^{20}\equiv 1\pmod {5^2},a^4\equiv 1\pmod 5.$

$A\equiv (1^1+2^2+3^3+\cdots+20^{20})+(21^1+22^2+\cdots40^{20})+\cdots+(81^1+\cdots+100^{20})\\ \equiv(1+21+41+61+81)+\sum_{k=0}^4\sum_{i=2}^{20}(20k+i)^i
\\\equiv 5+\sum_{k=0}^4\sum_{i=2}^{20}(i^i+i\cdot20k\cdot i^{i-1})
\\\equiv 5+\sum_{k=0}^4(20k+1)\sum_{i=2}^{20}i^i
\\\equiv 5+5\sum_{i=2}^{20}i^i
\\\equiv 5\sum_{i=1}^{20}i^i \pmod {25}$

$\sum_{i=1}^{20}i^i\equiv (1+2^2+3^3+4^0)+(1^2+2^3+3^0+4^1)+(1^3+2^0+3^1+4^2)+(1^0+2^1+3^2+4^3)
\\\equiv 3+4+1+1=4\pmod5
\\\implies A \equiv 20\not \equiv 0\pmod{25},A\equiv 0\pmod 5$

It's easy to find that $A$ is even, hence $10\mid A,100\nmid A.$ Hence there is only one zero at the end of $A$.